# Hide table using ngOnInit

Tags: angular, html-table, hide, ngoninit

I need to hide a particular column in the HTML table when the page loads. I used ngOnInit() to hide the column. But it works only for the `<th>` and not for `<td>`.

But, when I used in click function it works for both `<th>` and `<td>`.
How can I achieve this?

this is my code used in `ngOnInit`

```
ngOnInit() {
$('td:nth-child(19),#tr1 th:nth-child(8)').hide();
}
```

Comment: Try putting it in the life cycle `NgAfterViewChecked`, if I've understood right.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make the particular column depend on a boolean element using ngIf.
For example:

```
// ----- component.html -----
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>column1</th>
    <th>column2</th> 
    <th *ngIf="!eliminar">columnInvisible</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td> 
  </tr>
</table>

// ------ component.ts ------
export class LoginViewComponent implements OnInit {

  eliminar: boolean;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.eliminar = true;
  }

}
```